# Firebase snapshot reference gives Expression of type 'Any?' is unused warning

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The part snapshot.value here in the line

"ref.child("users/(followedUser!.name)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value){
(snapshot) in snapshot.value"

gives me a "Expression of type 'Any?' is unused" when I am getting my firebase snapshot. Could someone tell me where the warning is coming from and how to fix the warning? It is highlighting the value part of the snapshot.value.

```
//Get and parse user info.

        ref.child("users/\(followedUser!.name)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value){
            (snapshot) in snapshot.value
            
            //Get user.
            if let user = snapshot.value as? [String : [String:Any]]
            {
                //This is the holder for the goals we are about to build.
                var userGoals = [Goal]()
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is this code

```
(snapshot) in snapshot.value
```

Try to remove snapshot.value, to:

```
(snapshot) in
```

> Because snapshot.value in first call is never used.

Your finish code should be:

```
ref.child("users/\(followedUser!.name)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value){ (snapshot) in
   //Get user.
   if let user = snapshot.value as? [String : [String:Any]]
   {
       //This is the holder for the goals we are about to build.
       var userGoals = [Goal]()
   }
}
```